# When serial downvoting on answers is reversed, does the perpetrator get that rep back?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

A few hours ago, I was (or I guess so) a victim of serial downvoting:

[image]

I'm quite new here (for months now), but of course I'm confident that this will be reversed by the system script and those points will be refunded.

My question is: Once it's reversed and my points restored, does the perpetrator also (because these are all answers) get those points that was deducted?

Comment: SInce the votes will be reversed, the points will too.

Comment: /OT 16K+ rep within 3 month is remarkable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ im just lucky i get to spend more time answering since there are no projects coming up yet.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ for example, Martijn Peters earned 40k for this time.

Comment: I never thought of that... they should probably still get dinged.  If they see a reversal, then they might try to do it again.

Comment: @Will, NO, if the same user is continuously doing serial up/down vote; most probably he/she will get bann (OR) removed from the site.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The votes are undone, made null and void, and any reputation loss from voting on answers is refunded (as if they were never taken away in the first place).

The serial voter will end up with a 'serial voting undone' entry in their private reputation stream.

Comment: I would add that serial voting undone event also likely makes it [harder to repeat abuse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144478/165773 "reversal may be triggered at lower threshold") (at least against the same user)

Comment: oh okay, so other side gets refunded as well. okay thanks for this info

Comment: I wonder, would it be better to penalize the serial down-voter for their misbehaviour, either by not refunding their rep-loss through the down-votes (simple — at least from the outside of the system) or more dramatically by taking away the same amount of rep-loss again?  Or maybe first time offenders get their down-votes back, second time offenders don't, and the third time they lose the down-votes a second time, and after that, they get barred from the site for not learning basic social behaviours.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think it is more than plenty to just revert and show how futile the behaviour is.

Comment: Martijn, does this reversal have any count (count of question being downvoted/upvoted) check? Asking cause, recently two of my old answer got serial downvoted but I don't see they are reversed till date.

Comment: @rahul: if not reverted within 24 hours then it wasn't seen as a serial downvote. Generally speaking, just 2 downvotes is not seen as a serial vote.

Comment: Understood Martijn. was curious, cause those downvote was meaningless

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, good idea. Kinda like when you frivolously sue, you have to pay the defendant's legal fees also.